# How to import Data into MySQL workbench and create an ID when data has multiple duplicates

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, import-from-excel

This has been bugging me for a while and I can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

I am working with an Excel file provided by the French Government concerning sales of homes and apartments during the 1st semester 2020. All sales are recorded for that time period. The Excel file has over 30K different sales recorded.

Now, I want to import City data into a Table (named City) but obviously there are multiple mentions of the same cities (for instance: in Paris, in that time period, there have been over 2K sales).

So how do I tell MySQL workbench that when importing the City data it should only mention Paris once and give it 1 ID? And obviously also for all the other cities that are mentioned multiple times in the City column.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: You already have the City table created that expects an integer in place of the city name with another table making that association? Or are you expecting this to all be created on the import? You might have to import into a temp table first so you can aggregate your data.

Comment: @Phaelaxz I have created a Table with 3 attributes: ID (PK auto incremented), City (varchar) and State (well, Département because it's a French Data set)(varchar). It will eventually be associated to a real estate Table that gives details about each item sold (sqm, type of item (apartment or house) and # of rooms) which in turn will be associated to a sales Table with amount and date. But at the moment I'm struggling with this already so I haven't created those yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using workbench's built-in tools for this, but you could do the following (or load the csv into the temp table through the workbench tools then run the other insert queries)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempData (
    city varchar(64), 
    state varchar(64), 
);

TRUNCATE TABLE tempData;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "data.csv" INTO TABLE tempData FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@var1,@var2)
SET city=lower(@var1), state=@var2;


INSERT INTO cities (id, name) SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tempData;


INSERT INTO myRealTable (id, city, state) SELECT cities.id, tempData.state FROM tempData LEFT JOIN cities ON tempData.city = cities.name;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. With some adjustments it worked!